# Center a div inside a div. The div inside must be smaller than the parent div. Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to have a div inside a div like in the drawing below:

[image]

Is it even possible. I mean. Why in the world it is so difficult.  I just want a mofo div centered inside a mofo div, but not with 100% width/height.

My code:

```
<!-- Fotos servicios -->
<div id="div-servicios" class="container mt-2 mb-4">
    <div  class="row justify-content-center align-items-center fondo-negro-trans">
        <div id="serv-titulo" class="display-4 text-uppercase">
            <b>cortes</b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowfondo-negro-trans text-muted">
            <p class="lead">
                    Cortar con frecuencia el cabello, por lo menos cada tres meses, ayuda a eliminar las puntas dobles.

                    Quienes tienen el cabello con tratamientos químicos, como coloraciones o alisados permanentes necesitan de cuidados extra. 
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div-servicios {
    background-image: url("../media/index/index-f2.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 566px !important;
}

#serv-titulo{
    margin: 60px;
    left: 100px;    
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting both bits of text centered within the container or the serv div centered in the row? This is how I would do it with both bits centred - not sure how your row gets more height than the col though so I just added 500px height for demo: https://www.bootply.com/QVHEFJRq13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` and `margin:auto` to center a component inside another, and it makes it responsive.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dawn - yes there is. If you want to use Bootstrap's own utility classes, see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/

Comment: Also, why are you using vw instead of px?

Comment: @dawn I'm using this as an example to show it resizes correctly. It also works with pixels but it's less likely to be that way in the real project.

Answer (score 1):

There's numerous ways you can do this. Here's one of them, using absolute positioning:

```css
.outer-div {
border: 3px solid green;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
}

.inner-div {
border: 3px solid red;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
<div class="inner-div">
</div>
</div>
```

Here's another example, using flexbox:

```css
.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 400px;
}

.inner-div {
border: 3px solid green;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
<div class="inner-div">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it fully responsive try this code.

```
// html file
<div class="container">
        <div class="outer-div">
                <div class="inner-div">
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In your CSS file use this code.

```
.outer-div {
   border: 3px solid blue;
   height: 300px;
   position: relative;
}

.inner-div {
   border: 3px solid goldenrod;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[image]